# Unable to read data file and getting exception during TestRunner execution

Tags: karate

I am unable to read data.json file while running my Test Runner because its adding duplicate file path at run time. Need help to resolve this issue  IN Karate JUnit 5 or Karate Core

Note: TestRunner, .feature and Data.json are part of src/test/java but in two different packages. However, i tried putting data file, .feature and test runner in same package but still having same issue.

**Original Data.json path:**

C:\Users\LHCP\eclipse-workspace\APITESTING\src\test\java\Karate\APITESTING\TestData\data.json

**New Path at run time which is causing issue-**
C:\Users\LHCP\eclipse-workspace\APITESTING\target\test-classes\APITESTING\C:\Users\LHCP\eclipse-workspace\APITESTING\src\test\java\Karate\APITESTING\TestData\data.json (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

**Exception:**

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: js failed:

> > > > 

01: read('C:\Users\LHCP\eclipse-workspace\APITESTING\src\test\java\Karate\APITESTING\TestData\data.json');
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\LHCP\eclipse-workspace\APITESTING\target\test-classes\APITESTING\C:\Users\LHCP\eclipse-workspace\APITESTING\src\test\java\Karate\APITESTING\TestData\data.json (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

- com.intuit.karate.resource.FileResource.getStream(FileResource.java:98)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsStream(ScenarioFileReader.java:99)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsString(ScenarioFileReader.java:95)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFile(ScenarioFileReader.java:54)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.lambda$new$0(ScenarioEngine.java:124)
- .:program(Unnamed:1)
  Need help to resolve this issue as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are using absolute paths please use the `file:` prefix: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path-prefixes

Else it indeed could be a bug for windows in Karate. If you can follow this process, we will fix it: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi Peter Thomas, Using file:  as a prefix for .json or .csv file worked for but we are still this very same issue while trying to call one feature file in another feature file. Your input would be appreciated      

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\LHCP\eclipse-workspace\APITESTING\target\test-classes\APITESTING\C:\Users\LHCP\eclipse-workspace\APITESTING\src\test\java\APITESTING\accessToken.feature 
==============
.feature file sample code
===============
* def getToken = call read ('C:\\Users\\LHCP\\eclipse-workspace\\APITESTING\\src\\test\\java\\APITESTING\\accessToken.feature')

Comment: @SimonSimon as I said it may be a bug. the ONLY way I can help you is if you help me replicate this. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - but seriously, you should NEVER use absolute paths. and try using forward-slashes, they work in karate even in windows and don't need to be escaped. - and when you call another feature, did you try using `this:` ?

Comment: karate.call("accessToken.feature") worked for me.